# broadcast receiver in android

Tags: android, sms

I am creating an application which receives and parses SMS then sends data to another class.

So, for that I create a broadcast receiver but problem is that after receiving and parsing SMS, I cant call my class whom I have to send data.

Anyone have any idea how to implement the SMS receiver, and after receiving the SMS parse it and send data to another class which extends to activity ?

Receiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    int flag1=0,flag2=0,xyz=0;
    public String data = "",Lat="", Long="";
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null; 
    Bundle bundle; 
    Context con;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        con = context;

        //---get the SMS message passed in---

        bundle = intent.getExtras();               

        if (bundle != null)
        {
            //---retrieve the SMS message received---
           /* Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];    

            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++)
            {
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);                
                //data += "SMS from " + msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();                     
                //data += " :";
                data += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
                //data += "\n";        


            }*/

            data = "Lalazar Ave Hayatabad Pakistan;lat:33.978410 long:71.430398,T:2011-02-25\n19:37,speed:0";
            //---display the new SMS message---
            Toast.makeText(context, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Exract_Langitude_And_Latitude();

        }                        
    }


    public void Exract_Langitude_And_Latitude()
    {
        Toast.makeText(con, "Getting Latitude & Longitude", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        for ( int i = 0; i < data.length(); ++i )
         {
              char c = data.charAt(i); 
              String s = Character.toString(c);

              ///finding latitude
              if (s.equals(";"))
              {
                Toast.makeText(con, "Getting Latitude", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                flag1=1;
                String str="";
                str = data;

                for (int  j= i+5;j<str.length();j++)  
                {
                char ch = str.charAt(j);
                String l = Character.toString(ch);  
                Lat+=l;

                int k = j+6;

                char ch1 = str.charAt(k);
                String m = Character.toString(ch1);

                if (m.equals(":"))
                {
                xyz = k;    
                break;  
                }

                }

                Toast.makeText(con, "Latitude = "+ Lat, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }


              ///finding longitude
              if (s.equals(":") && i == xyz )
              {
                Toast.makeText(con, "Getting Longitude", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                flag2=1;
                //System.out.println("found at i = "+i);  
                String str="";
                str = data;

                for (int j = i+1;j<str.length();j++)  
                {
                char ch = str.charAt(j);  
                String l = Character.toString(ch);  
                Long+=l;

                int k = j+1;
                char ch1 = str.charAt(k);
                String m = Character.toString(ch1); 
                if (m.equals(","))
                break;      
                }

                Toast.makeText(con, "Longitude = " + Long, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              if (flag1==1 && flag2==1)
              {
                 Toast.makeText(con, "Forget You", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
                // Intent serviceIntent = new Intent().setClassName(con, Post.class.getName());
                 //con.startService(serviceIntent);
                 //con.startActivity(serviceIntent);                 

                /* Intent in = new Intent(SmsReceiver.this,Post.class);
                 in.startActivity();*/
             break; 
              }
         }///end of main for loop
    }  
}
```

Activity:

```
package com.sms;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.gsm.SmsMessage;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class smsMessaging extends Activity {


        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", ""); 
            sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            startActivity(sendIntent);

           /* SmsReceiver obj = new SmsReceiver();
            String a = obj.Lat;
            String b = obj.Long; 
            Toast.makeText(smsMessaging.this, "Latitude = "+ a +"  "+ "Longitude = "+ b, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */

        /* Intent intent = new Intent (this,Post.class);
         startActivity(intent);*/

        }

}
```

Comment: why can't you call the class? can you show us the code where you try to start the new Activity?

Comment: can u please tell me how to post code here ? because iam new and dn't know

Comment: You'll want to edit your original question and add it, if you don't format it quite right I can edit your post and fix the formatting.

Comment: thanks :) i had posted it above now whats the problem ?

Comment: nopes it dosnt work thats y i commented it :(

Answer (score 2):

Mudasar,

Assuming you intend to launch `smsMessaging` from the `BroadcastReceiver` you will want to do something like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(con, smsMessaging.class);
con.startActivity(i);
```

If you need to send any information to the `smsMessaging Activity`.  You can use `i.putExtra()` before your call to `startActivity(i)`.

You must also make sure you've added the `smsMessaging Activity` to your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: its nt working showung the problem   "The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SmsReceiver" , "createmethod startActivity(intent)"

Comment: still same error  The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type SmsReceiver

Comment: ahh! try `con.startActivity(i);` sorry >< forgot you were in a `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: do you have the logcat output?  it could be launching the new activity then immediately crashing.